# Setting cookie in browser using AWS API Gateway and lambda

Tags: cookies, browser, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Trying to set a cookie through AWS lambda and API gateway, by following this [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/simply-serverless-using-aws-lambda-to-expose-custom-cookies-with-api-gateway/).

After following the steps, a cookie is seen in the response headers,(i.e. it shows in the developer tools -> Network -> Cookies), but the cookie is not set in the browser (i.e. does not persist at all).

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: This approach only works for the same domain, beware. It's also an option to set cookie the in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. By removing the domain parameter completely.

This resource [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie), shows there is no syntax with all three parameters. Not sure if that is best way to go about this but it worked.

Cheers.